Blender gives a `NameError` error when calling get_strokes()
I'm currently working on an addon for Blender that turns the camera view into an SVG. There's this error that shows up when I try calling get_strokes()
File "d:\Blender builds\Blender 4.2.1\4.2\scripts\freestyle\modules\freestyle\utils.py", line 95, in get_strokes
    return tuple(map(Operators().get_stroke_from_index, range(Operators().get_strokes_size())))
 
NameError: name 'Operators' is not defined

This function exists in Blender's api.
It's the first time I'm coding an addon for Blender, so I might be missing something obvious.
To replicate this, you can set up a Python 3.7 environment and install bpy and numpy, and finally run bpy_post_install. For example on Conda:
conda create -n blender python=3.7 -y
conda activate blender
pip install bpy numpy
bpy_post_install

Then run the following code:
import bpy
from freestyle.utils import get_strokes

var = get_strokes()

I really need to get the strokes from the freestyle linesets for the project I'm working on at work. I'm now stuck on this part. I tried looking into the code of the existing addon Freestyle SVG Exporter to try to find how to do it, but I'm very lost.

What version of Python are you running?

Also, how did you install bpy?

Looking at the code (freestyle/modules/freestyle/utils.py) it is indeed unclear where the name Operators is supposed to be coming from. It's not imported or defined in that module, nor are there wildcard imports. Only get_strokes makes use of this - have you tried submitting a question at https://blender.stackexchange.com/ ?

@halfer I didn't install bpy per se, I have Blender installed and ran the code inside Blender itself.

@Grismar I did not, indeed, try to submit my question there. I was so tired that I didn't remember about its existence. I'll do that now. Thanks for the suggestion!

Coolio. It might be worth following the notes that Grismar has added to your question, in case there is a difference between doing this in Python and doing it in the Blender environment.
